# Setting the default ribbon tab to a custom tab in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom-actions

Ok - So I have a shared documents library - and like many posts before me I would like to make the default tab on the ribbon a custom tab that I have made.  Can someone tell me how to edit the URL using code without having to manually type in the url aspx?InitialRibbonID=Ribbon.CustomTabExample......
PLEASE

Answer (score 1):

Try manipulating the [InitialTabId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.commandui.ribbon.initialtabid.aspx) of the SPRibbon object. Set the attribute value to the id to your tab and then it will be selected when the document library loads.

Here is a sample example: http://kmukesh.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/how-to-create-custom-site-ribbon-tab-with-buttons/